# How likely it is to get a job in programming in Germany for a non-EU without a degree?

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, europe

I know the question might be a bit too specific, but I'm interested in knowing these details preferably from people who might already have had a successful experience.

Basically: I don't have any college degree, I only have skills. I already understand the process for application (such as the fact that I need a signed job offer) and I know that it IS technically possible to get it because there's no law saying you can't get a work visa without a degree. However, it's also technically possible for Merkel herself to issue an honorary German citizenship for me, but we all know that's unlikely.

I'd like to add that I speak German and have the official certificates from the Goethe center, would that help in gaining a visa?

Furthermore I'd like to add that I'm talking about a normal work visa, I know that the blue card requires a degree.

So, assuming that I pass an interview and get an offer, how likely would it be for the government to actually accept me?
Any success stories would be appreciated.